# What are the rulings of praying and follwing an Imam from outside a mosque when the mosque is crowded?

Tags: salat, fiqh, masjid

In the classical literature of fiqh scholars adress the issue of crowded mosques, and how to pray in a case a mosque is filled to overflowing.

[image]

But so far I couldn't find any explanation or rulings about the case that people can't pray inside due to the overflow. Or as it is the case in many mosques in Morocco and elseweher in the tarweeh prayer in ramadan or jumu'ah, that the mosque offers some straw mats and put them outside of a mosque and people who come late and can't find a place inside pray there following the imam.

So I'd like to have a ruling on that (rulings from all madhhabs are welcome)?

Answer (score 1):

You may read this ruling [(IslamQA)](https://islamqa.info/en/45611) which touches upon some difference in opinion on this matter within the Hanbali school. When the Mosque is too crowded (meaning the rows are uninterrupted), then per their view you may pray outside so long as you can hear the Imam and see him.

I find the above source to be reliable.

The below links are to aid you for your inquiry into the Shafi'i and Hanafi views. I am not totally sure about their content accuracy, though. So I suggest further research and verifying.

- [Shafi'i Fiqh](http://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/34044/barrier-between-the-imam-and-follower)
- [Hanafi Fiqh](http://islamqa.org/hanafi/qibla-hanafi/35468/does-the-follower-have-to-see-the-imam-for-the-prayer-to-be-valid)